# How to properly exit nested states in UML state diagrams?

Tags: uml, transition, automata, plantuml

I'm new at UML and I'm trying to document my software development process.  I made the following diagram with PlantUML:

[image]

Within the inner states, I'd like to show that once their respective releases (i.e. minor/patch) are made, the next-highest level state should be returned to.

For example, after `PatchRelease`, `Patch` should exit to `EvalStory`.  Ditto for `MinorRelease --> EvalEpic`.  How should I show this?  (An answer providing PlantUML code won't be necessary but would be nice)

```
[*] --> Major
state Major {
[*] --> CreateEpic
note right : An 'Epic' describes the set of desired\nfeatures the end-user would like to see
CreateEpic --> EvalEpic
EvalEpic --> Minor : unfulfilled
EvalEpic --> MajorRelease : fulfilled
MajorRelease --> [*]

state Minor {
[*] --> CreateStory
CreateStory --> EvalStory
EvalStory --> Patch : unfulfilled
EvalStory --> MinorRelease : fulfilled
MinorRelease --> DeployLive

state Patch {
[*] --> Testing
Testing --> DeployTest
DeployTest --> EvalTest
EvalTest --> Testing : bugs found
EvalTest --> PatchRelease: no bugs found

state Testing {
[*] --> WriteTests
WriteTests --> RunTests

RunTests --> WriteCode: test(s) failed
RunTests  -left-> WriteTests: tests passed
WriteCode --> RunTests
}
Patch --> EvalStory

}
Minor --> EvalEpic

}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, after PatchRelease, Patch should exit to EvalStory

That is already happening, as that is the default behavior.

Once *PatchRelease* has finished, there's nowhere else to go, so the *Patch* finishes its operation and then you can look at it again as if there were no states inside *Patch*.

If you want to be explicit, you can

1. add a final state after EvalStory, so a reader knows that you really meant to end there and it wasn't an accidental omission
2. use entry/exit states; unfortunately PlantUML doesn't support those

you can read on entry/exit states for example here http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html#exit-point-pseudostate

Comment: Actually Peter's answer is more complete. We've posted at the same time so I upvoted this one and recommend the same to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Add final pseudostate after the last state inside a compound state.

E.g. If you add code

PatchRelease --> [*]

it'll mean that after PatchRelease is completed also the whole Patch is completed and thus it can move to next state (which is EvalStory)

Comment: Note that final state is an actual state, not a pseudostate.